# how to avoid additional files created by vim in windows

Tags: windows, vim

When I create a new file in `gvim`, and save it using `:wq filename`, it is creating two more additional files, and I need to manually delete them.

> E.g., I opened `gvim` and saved file `c:\dev\DeleteInvalidCustomers.md` using `:wq`

Now, I have got three files in `c:\dev\` folder

> DeleteInvalidCustomers.md
> DeleteInvalidCustomers.md~      ===> Additional File 1
> .DeleteInvalidCustomers.md.un~  ===> Additional File 2

These additional files remain in the disk, even after I close `vim`.
How can I avoid these additional files getting generated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File ending with `~` is swap file. File with extension `.un` is undo file.

Read in help:

- [`:h swap-file`](https://vimhelp.org/recover.txt.html#swap-file)
- [`:h undofile`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27undofile%27)
- [`:h crash-recovery`](https://vimhelp.org/recover.txt.html)
- [`:h undo-redo`](https://vimhelp.org/undo.txt.html)
- [`:h directory`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27directory%27)
- [`:h undodir`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27undodir%27)

EDIT:

> my doubt is, why they are still present, after I close `gvim` also

Swap file is used i.a. for recovering from crashes. There wouldn't be much use of it, if it was deleted. From what to recover?

Undo file stays, because you usually want to be able to make undo-redo in new Vim sessions too.

Comment: my doubt is, why they are still present, after I close `gvim` also